# Reference: Known properties of the possible values of the number of groups up to isomorphism of any finite order?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, soft-question, finite-groups

This question is a softer question: I'd like some reference for any information on the following if possible.

Say $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$. Define (for convenience of expressing statements in this question) the function $\mathcal{G}: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ where $\mathcal{G}(n)$ is the number of groups of order $n$ up to isomorphism, for example, for $p$ a prime, $\mathcal{G}(p)=1$, $\mathcal{G}(p^2)=2$, $\mathcal{G}(p^3)= 5$.

Some results about the values of $\mathcal{G}$ for particular natural numbers are not currently known, for example the value of $\mathcal{G}(2048)$.

But, can we say anything more generally about the possible values of $\mathcal{G}(n)$? That is,

- Do we know that any natural number can be the number of groups up to isomorphism of some natural number, that is, $\mathcal{G}(\mathbb{N}) = \mathbb{N}$? If so, are all values taken on an infinite number of times? (Of course some are, as given in the examples with prime powers)
- Or do we know the inverse, that $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \notin \mathcal{G}(\mathbb{N})$? If so, do we know such an $n$? Indeed, the smallest $n$? Are there any conditions on $n$ that classify when we can say for certain that $n \in \mathcal{G}(\mathbb{N})$ or $n \notin \mathcal{G}(\mathbb{N})$? Have we completely classified this for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or are some unknown?

Or is nothing here known?

Note a similar question (asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786525/abelian-groups-of-order-n)) for abelian groups is well understood since the number of abelian groups can be worked out using partitions. But non-abelian groups aren't nearly as easy to handle.

Comment: I suppose the answer is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787871/which-integers-are-a-product-of-partition-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1). Since $\mathcal{G}(n)$ is so rapidly growing, it will not represent all positive integers. But I don't know.

Comment: This function is widely known as the ${\mathrm{ gnu}}$ function, so you could search for that. It is am open problem whether there exists $n$ with ${\rm gnu}(n)=n$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Presumably you mean for $n>1$?

Comment: Yes I mean for $n>1$!

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/%7Eobrien/research/gnu.pdf) paper classifies precisely for which $n$, $\mathcal{G}(n)=\mathrm{gnu}(n)=1,2,3,4$. (See the section “the baby gnus”). It states the main part of my question “Every positive integer is a group number.” as a conjecture in the section “Hunting gnus and moas”. According to that paper, it has been established for all numbers up to $10000000$, they cite R. Keith Dennis.

I won’t accept my own answer here as if someone can find another reference with more information, I would greatly appreciate that.